# What does the following statement by Richard Dawkins mean?

Tags: biology, social-interaction

I am reading “*The Selfish Gene*” by Richard Dawkins in which the writer has to say this:

> ‘Welfare’ is defined as ‘chances of survival’, even if the effect on actual life and death prospects is so small as to *seem* negligible.

Comment: I think it means that any advantage can be significant, no matter how small it might appear to be to us.

Comment: I haven't read The Selfish Gene, does 'Welfare' in this passage refer to an individual organism, the species, or strain, of which the organism is a member or the individual gene? In general use "welfare" usually refers to individual organisms or small groups but this could be a technical use of the term.

Comment: An organism, the writer speaks with baboon as an example. I haven’t understood the part when he says that even if the effect on actual life and death prospects is so small to seem negligible.

Comment: I think that Dawkins means that an increase in the welfare of an organism will increase the _chances_  of its survival but, just because the odds on its survival have improved it isn't guaranteed to actually live longer.

Answer (score 2):

‘Welfare’ is defined as ‘chances of survival’, even if the effect ***[of that chance of survival]*** on actual life and death prospects (i.e. the chance of surviving) is so small as to seem negligible.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining so well. :)